# A workaround for visualization depends on and ybar stacked

Tags: pgfplots

Are there any workarounds for the [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3594497&group_id=224188&atid=1060656)?

> The "visualization depends on" function causes an error with stacked
>   plots.
>
> With "ybar stacked", the minimal example generates the error message
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \pgfplots@current@point@meta
>   ->{0Y0.0e0]},\test

I need numbers over stacked bars. These numbers must be calculated from another column.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar stacked, %this doesn't work
% ybar, % this works
% stack plots=y, % this doesn't work
visualization depends on=0.5*y \as \test
]

\addplot [nodes near coords=\test] table {
0 0
1 10
2 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the bug tracker this is fixed but not yet released to CTAN. When it is, I guess the answer will be to update.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which is fixed in the current release.